# Routing of a directive within a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been having some issues regarding routing of directives within directives. 
This is my app.config for ui-routing:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
        .state('modules', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/home/templates/module-panel.jsp'
        })

        .state('customer', {
            url: '/customer',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/customer/templates/customer-panel.jsp'
        })


        .state('customerProfile', {
            url: '/customer/customerProfile',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/customer/templates/customer-profile.jsp'
        })

        .state('customerList', {
            url: '/customer/customerList',
            templateUrl: 'resources/modules/customer/templates/customer-list.jsp'
        });
;
/*$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);*/
```

As far as my directives are concerned, the main directive is "customer" and its sub-directives are "customer-list" and "customer-profile" respectively.
This is the html for "customer" directive:

```
<span ng-controller="CustomerController as custCtrl">
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <ul class="menuList">
      <li class=""><a class="anime" ui-sref="customerList" ng-class="{active: custCtrl.customerListPanel}" ng-click="custCtrl.openCustomerList()">Customer List</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="anime" ui-sref="customerProfile" ng-class="{active: custCtrl.customerProfilePanel}" ng-click="custCtrl.openCustomerProfile()">Customer Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="custCtrl.customerListPanel">
    <customer-list></customer-list>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="custCtrl.customerProfilePanel">
    <customer-profile></customer-profile>
  </div>
</span>
```

But the problem is, when the control goes to either of "customer-profile" or "customer-list", the content of "customer" are gone. I want "customer" directive to act as the "master" and both of these directives should use the main "customer" template other than their respective html.

Comment: Don't see any directive like `<customer>`. Where is the data coming from? Sounds like you might be missing a service and certainly seem to be missing some `$stateParams` in url. Question itself is a bit confusing

Comment: The html shown above is actually the <customer> directive in which two additional directives <customer-profile> and <customer-list> are shown.

Comment: I really don't get it ...you want that directive all views then? And not clear why `content is lost`....no data source or controller code shown